Automatic Screen Capture Batch File
I have the batch file below which takes a screenshot every 5 seconds. This works well however I want to specify only a part of the display from which to take the screenshot using coordinates. I do not want the entire display to be captured. For example, assuming the bottom left corner is 0,0, I want to capture from 100,100 (bottom left corner) to 1000,1000 (top right comer). How do I modify the batch file to do this?
    @echo off
    REM https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/qadj3w/print_screen_batch/Title Get a ScreenShot with Batch and Powershell
    Set CaptureScreenFolder=C:\ScreenCapture\
    If Not Exist "%CaptureScreenFolder%" MD "%CaptureScreenFolder%"
    Set WaitTimeSeconds=5
    :Loop
        Call :ScreenShot
        echo ScreenShot is taken on %Date% @ %Time% in Folder "%CaptureScreenFolder%"
        Timeout /T %WaitTimeSeconds% /NoBreak>nul
    Goto Loop

::----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :ScreenShot
    Powershell ^
    $Path = '%CaptureScreenFolder%';^
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;^
    $screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds;^
    $image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($screen.Width, $screen.Height^);^
    $graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($image^);^
    $point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,0^);^
    $graphic.CopyFromScreen($point, $point, $image.Size^);^
    $cursorBounds = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position,[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Current.Size^);^
    [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default.Draw($graphic, $cursorBounds^);^
    $FileName = $((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_HH_mm_ss')+'.jpg');^
    $FilePath = $Path+$FileName;^
    $FormatJPEG = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::jpeg;^
    $image.Save($FilePath,$FormatJPEG^)
    Exit /B

I am not sure what to try

not familiar with PS, but looking at $graphic.CopyFromScreen($point, $point, $image.Size^);, where $point is defined as 0,0 and $image.Size as $screen.Width,$screen.Height looks like "selecting the whole screen"
